# json for displaying youtube video description and view count is not working after a youtube update

Tags: php, json

I have a facebook like wall, in my project, that when a user posts a youtube link, it is displayed like in facebook wall. First the image and then the description and the views. My code used to work sucessfully, but after an update at youtube, there are bugs, Image displayed sucessfully but not the title, description and the views. Any ideas how to fix this? This is my code for getting title, video description and views count:

```
<?php

$find_youtube = "://www.youtube.com/";

if(preg_match('~MSIE|Internet Explorer~i', $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'])) {
  if(preg_match("[$find_youtube]", $row['comment'])){

  parse_str( parse_url( $row['comment'], PHP_URL_QUERY ), $my_array_of_vars );

  $regex='#(?<=v=)[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(?=&)|(?<=[0-9]/)[^&\n]+|(?<=v=)[^&\n ]+#';
  preg_match($regex, $row['comment'], $mid);

  $id = $mid[0];

  $json_output = file_get_contents("http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/{$id}?v=2&alt=json");
  $json = json_decode($json_output, true);
  $video_title = $json['entry']['title']['$t'];
  $video_description = $json['entry']['media$group']['media$description']['$t'];
  $view_count = $json['entry']['yt$statistics']['viewCount'];
  $video_perigrafh = substr($video_description , 0, 160);

  }
}

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can call Video.list() method of V3 API To get the video resource with all the associated details. Check following link:

https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos

```
$json_output = file_get_contents("https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?id={$id}&part=snippet,statistics&alt=json");
$json = json_decode($json_output, true);
$video_title = $json['entry']['snippet']['title'];
$video_description = $json['entry']['snippet']['description'];
$view_count = $json['entry']['statistics']['viewCount'];
$video_perigrafh = substr($video_description , 0, 160);
```

Comment: in my case any idea how I should change the above code with this?

Comment: try it...looking good, but still not working. Any idea what it might missing?

Comment: @33528 Rectified the url for Youtube Video List API. Also try dumping $json in your code to see what you get when making the call.